How to validate select drop down in python playwright?
In my webpage select drop down (months values from 1 to 12) .When I open the page already month 3 default selected.I want to select value 5 for the drop down
select_dropdown = page.query_selector('//div[3]//select[1]')

# 2.clear already selected value
select_dropdown.select_option(value=" ")
select month 5
select_dropdown.select_option('//div[3]//select[1]', label='5')


Can you share the page (or a reprex of it) and a [mcve] of the code, and describe your high-level goal clearly? XPath is discouraged: "CSS and XPath are not recommended as the DOM can often change leading to non resilient tests. Instead, try to come up with a locator that is close to how the user perceives the page such as role locators or define an explicit testing contract using test ids.".
